# Plotting extremely small Y-axis values in ggplot

Tags: ggplot2, scale, scatter-plot, yaxis

In my data, some values of which are extremely small, as small as e-19. When I plot the data, those small values are clustered around zero.

Suppose I have 21 datapoints; 20 of which are ranging from e-05 to e-02 and 1 of which has a value of 1.

```
my.df <- data.frame(group=state.name[1:21],col1 = c(runif(20,min=1e-05,max=1e-02),1))

p <- ggplot(my.df, aes(x=group,y=col1)) +
 geom_point()
```

I want to have more precise y axis values so that those small values would spread more, not only stuck around zero. Preferably, I would like to have y values to increase in a geometric scale such as e-05, e-04, e-03, e-02, e-01, 1, something like this scale.

Thank you for your support in advance!

PS: I carefully checked if there is a replicate. I hope I haven't missed an already existing one.

Comment: maybe just use a logarithmic scale - i.e., for example add `+
   scale_y_log10()` to your plot

Comment: That worked, so simple. Thanks. Perhaps, I was thinking of a scaling solution much more complicated than that.